# Reduce and Solve give incorrect answers for trigonometric equation

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

Why use Reduce and Solve to solve the Trigonometric functions equation with incorrect  results?

```
Reduce[{0 < a < π, Sin[a] + Cos[a] == 1/5, 
   Sin[a]^2 + Cos[a]^2 == 1, Cos[a] tana == Sin[a]}, {tana, Sin[a], 
   Cos[a]}] // FullSimplify
```

and

```
Reduce[{0 < a < π, Sin[a] + Cos[a] == 1/5, 
  Sin[a]^2 + Cos[a]^2 == 1}, {Sin[a], Cos[a]}, Reals]
```

and

```
Solve[{0 < a < π, Sin[a] + Cos[a] == 1/5, 
   Sin[a]^2 + Cos[a]^2 == 1, Cos[a] tana == Sin[a]}, {tana, Sin[a], 
   Cos[a]}, Reals] // FullSimplify
```

The details are as follows

[image]

The result of the manual calculation is as follows:

[image]

The sign of the sine function between 0 and PI is positive, obviously this answer is incorrect

[image]

Comment: The variables in your equation is messes up. If you try `Reduce[0 < x < 1 && x + y == 1/5 && x^2 + y^2 == 1 && 
  y tana == x, {tana, x, y}]` and `Solve[0 < x < 1 && x + y == 1/5 && x^2 + y^2 == 1 && 
  y tana == x, {tana, x, y}, Reals]`, you will find the result is same.

Comment: `{Sin[a], Cos[a], Tan[a]} /. Solve[{0 < a < Pi, Sin[a] + Cos[a] == 1/5, Sin[a]^2 + Cos[a]^2 == 1}, a] // FullSimplify`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Solve[{0 < a < π, Sin[a] + Cos[a] == 1/5, 
   Cos[a] tana == Sin[a]}, {tana}, {a}, Reals] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're stoping `Solve` and `Reduce` from analyzing `a` (if it's not a wrong way to use `Solve` and `Reduce`). A much simpler example showing the issue:

```
Solve[{Sin[a] == 2}, Sin[a], Reals]
(* {{Sin[a] -> 2}} *)
```

What's happening here? Because we've set `Sin[a]` as 2nd argument of `Solve`, `Solve` has treated the whole `Sin[a]` as an unknown variable, what's inside `Sin[a]` is not analyzed at all. What has happened here is just the same as

```
Solve[{我是一个表达式头部[我是一个参数] == 2}, 我是一个表达式头部[我是一个参数], Reals]
(* {{我是一个表达式头部[我是一个参数] -> 2}} *)
```

So, if you want `Solve` and `Reduce` to analyze the `Sin` and `Cos`, use `a` rather than `Sin[a]` or `Cos[a]` as the variable:

```
Tan[a] /. 
  Solve[{0 < a < π, Sin[a] + Cos[a] == 1/5}, a][[1]] // FullSimplify
(* -(4/3) *)
```

If you insist on fixing your code:

```
vars = {Sin[a], Cos[a]};
Solve[Flatten@{FunctionRange[{#, 0 < a < π}, a, #] & /@ vars, 
   Sin[a] + Cos[a] == 1/5, Sin[a]^2 + Cos[a]^2 == 1}, vars]
(* {{Sin[a] -> 4/5, Cos[a] -> -(3/5)}} *)
```

The keypoint is to use `FunctionRange` to do the analysis that `Solve`/`Reduce` won't do in this case.